# How to perform synchronous api call in retrofit 1.9

Tags: android, retrofit

I am getting android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException exception while calling api synchronously. I cannnot use Async call as I have many apis and next api is dependent on output of previous api call.

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Declare the method in your retroft interface as following:

> @GET("/v1/user_info/{id}")
>   UserSummaryResponse getSummary(@Path("id")
>   String uId);

You need to start a new thread in your networking request calling, and don't forget **try catch.**

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
      try {
        GetSummaryResponse summaryResponse = HttpClientManager.getInstance().userInterface.getSummary(uId);
        userInfo = summaryResponse.userInfo;
                            setupUserInfo();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        withoutException = false;
        Log.e(getTag(), e.getMessage());
      }

 }}).start();
```